# Slow solid state drive on laptop running Linux

Tags: linux, laptop, ssd

I installed a solid state drive on my laptop, but I don't get the blazing speeds which people write about.

My system:

- Laptop: Acer Aspire 7552G-6061
- Solid state drive: Crucial 256GB M4 CT256M4SSD2
- Operating system: Linux (Trisquel 5.5, a derivative of Ubuntu)

I am using AHCI.

I installed the operating system onto the solid state drive (as opposed to copying it).

How can I make the solid state drive faster? Could the problem be with the block or sector alignment?

Comment: It would be helpful to know exactly what performance issues you are encountering.

Comment: I didn't time things, but the bootup time might be a little faster, and the showdown time is about the same. When I open a 6 MB file in LibreOffice Calc, I can still see the progress bar move as Calc loads it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answering Your Questions First

- The problem should not be related to sector alignment.
- I have two tips below for keeping up performance on SSDs.

### Understanding SSD Benefits

The "blazing speeds" people experience on solid-state drives are referring to **reading from and writing to the drive**.  Compared to hard disk drives, SSDs have **very low access times** and **higher data transfer rates**, especially when accessing randomly.

Operations beyond reading and writing data to the SSD do not have a performance increase, such as using the processor to make intensive calculations.  *If your expectation from your SSD is to have performance improvements for CPU or RAM operations, this is why you aren't getting the "blazing speeds".*

Did you notice your **boot time decrease** dramatically transitioning from an HDD to an SSD?  I used to be frustrated at my laptop for taking over **50 seconds** to boot.  Now, with my own Crucial 256GB m4 CT256M4SSD2, my laptop boots in no more than **12 seconds** (and this includes running a full [LAMP server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29)!)

When a computer is booting from an HDD, files have to be read from different physical locations.  The seek time of the reading head moving to the next location is a huge performance killer.  The Crucial m4 has an average access time of **0.1 ms**.  The hard drive I had before (a Toshiba MK6461GSYN) has an average access time of **15.8 ms**.  Not only is the SSD much faster, it also reads and writes over twice as fast (240+ MB/s) as my HDD can (120 MB/s maximum).

If you haven't experienced a huge decrease in boot time, I can't guess why from the information you provided.  To some people who are wondering why I haven't suggested [TRIM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18903/how-to-enable-trim), it's because TRIM isn't relevant yet.  TRIM is only useful for writing to the SSD, but booting an operating system is primarily reading.

### Improving SSD Performance on Linux

There are only two things that I recommend.

1. [Enabling TRIM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18903/how-to-enable-trim)
2. [Setting `noatime`](http://www.howtogeek.com/62761/how-to-tweak-your-ssd-in-ubuntu-for-better-performance/)

#### Enabling TRIM

*TRIM keeps the write performance of your SSD like-new by telling the SSD what sectors are no longer in use and thus, reducing write amplification.*

In a terminal, run the command `sudo nano /etc/fstab`.

Use the arrow keys and find the entry or entries that are partitions on your SSD.  For each entry, add `discard` to the options. A line may look something like this afterwards:

```
UUID=ed586ab8-08c5-4bae-b118-d191b716b4a4 /               ext4    discard,errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

Skip to the section below to apply `noatime` as well, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>, type <kbd>Y</kbd>, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the changes.

#### Setting `noatime`

*`noatime` tells the filesystem not to write to files when they were last accessed.  Logging latest access times, in most cases, is not necessary and is a waste of effort on both SSDs and HDDs.*

Like the section above, make sure that you've run the command `sudo nano /etc/fstab` and are in the nano text editor.

Use the arrow keys and find the entry or entries that are partitions on your SSD. For each entry, add `noatime` to the options. A line may look something like this afterwards:

```
UUID=ed586ab8-08c5-4bae-b118-d191b716b4a4 /               ext4    noatime,discard,errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

Comment: Possibly some of my usage is CPU- and RAM-intensive. Your answer was informative, and including examples was good. I know nano, but it was nice that you went through the steps for saving.